# Matlab Standalone Compiler problem with uigetfile

Tags: macos, matlab, compiler-errors, matlab-compiler

I am running Matlab r2011a on a mac osx lion.

I use uigetfile in my matlab environment and it works fine.  However, as soon as I compile a standalone app, it decides to not show my uigetfile window when I call it. Any idea what could be wrong?

Thanks

CODE:

```
% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton1.
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
[handles.file,handles.dir] = uigetfile('*.xls');

set(handles.edit1,'String',strcat(handles.dir,handles.file));
guidata(hObject,handles);
drawnow('expose');
drawnow('update');
```

Comment: I suggest that you take this issue to Mathworks support.